# How to debug the error "Deprecated: curl_setopt():"

Tags: php

I have an old script that uploads PDF files via an API. I'm getting the error message:

> Deprecated: curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file
>    uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead.

Here is the relevant code (I think this is all of it). The error points to the line: `curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields )`.

```
//Upload the file
    function uploadPdf( $api, $lead_id, $rev, $existing_files = array() ) {

        if ( ! file_exists( SERVERPATH . "quotes/quote-". $this->id .".pdf" ) )
            $this->createQuotePdf();

        $files_array = array( array( 'entityType'=>'files', 'name'=>"quote-". $this->id .".pdf" ) );

        // if ( $this->upfile && ! file_exists( SERVERPATH . "uploads/" . $upfile ) )
        //  $files_array[] = array( array( 'entityType'=>'files', 'name'=> $upfile ) );

        foreach ( $existing_files as $file ) {
            $files_array[] = (array) $file;
        }

        //this request gives us the URLs to upload to
        $result = $api->editLead( array( 'leadId' => $lead_id, 'rev'=>'REV_IGNORE', 'lead'=> array( 'file' => $files_array ) ) );

        //Upload the Quote file
        $postFields = array();      

        $postFields['file'] = "@" . SERVERPATH . "quotes/quote-". $this->id .".pdf";

        $postFields['type'] = "application/pdf";
        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        $file = array_pop( $result->file );
        curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $file->uri );
        curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, USERNAME . ":" . API_KEY );
        curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields );
        //execute the API Call
        $return  = curl_exec( $curl_handle ) ;

        $this->uploadUpfile($api, $lead_id);

        return $return;

    }
```

My knowledge is pretty basic. But I've tried to replace:

```
$postFields['file'] = "@" . SERVERPATH . "quotes/quote-". $this->id .".pdf";
$postFields['type'] = "application/pdf";
```

with

```
$postFields['file'] = curl_file_create(SERVERPATH . "quotes/quote-". $this->id .".pdf", 'application/pdf', SERVERPATH . "quotes/quote-". $this->id .".pdf");
```

Doing the above has got rid of the error, but the underlying problem where I can't actually open the uploaded file is still happening. So I'm wondering if I've done something wrong?

Comment: Correct you use http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php instead of the `@` notation

Comment: Explicitly answering the question "Is this the way to solve “Deprecated: curl_setopt():” error?" - Yes. Use something else. It's deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP 5.5 and above you should use CURLFile to upload file, I have already posted a complete answer describing CURLFile and normal file upload, you can check that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46190111/2520628).

You can use CURLFile as below, feel free to adjust the code as per your need:

```
//Upload file using CURLFile
function upload($target, $postFields){
    $file = $postFields['file'];

    $cFile = new CURLFile($file,$postFields['type'], $file);
    $data = array(
        'file' => $cFile,
        'type' => $postFields['type'],
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER  , true); //we need header
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // stop verifying certificate
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // enable posting
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // post images 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // if any redirection after upload
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
    $r = curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error = curl_error($curl);
        print_r($error);
    } else {
        // check the HTTP status code of the request
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($resultStatus != 200) {
            print_r($resultStatus);
        }else{
            //successfull
            print_r($r);
        }
    }
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

As your file and filetype are in an array named `$postFields`, so you can call the above function as below:

`upload($target, $postFields);`

where `$target` is the link which you are calling to upload the file.

Comment: Thank you for your help Tejashwi - I've just edited the code in the original question to show the complete function to hopefully give a more complete picture. Because in my function the file is in an array, do I need to alter your line here:  $file = "@" . SERVERPATH . "quotes/quote-". $this->id .".pdf";
or any other line?