# How to upload file to api via curl post

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, codeigniter-2, php-curl

This is the $_POST

```
Array
(
 [name] => image.png
 [type] => image/png 
 [tmp_name] => C:\xampp5\tmp\phpA637.tmp
 [error] => 0
 [size] => 16412
)
```

And here's the code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_PORT => "2403",
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://".cfg('api_ip').":2403/sk_group/update_profile_pic", //url
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n\r\n{\"groupId\":\"".$group."\",\"profile_pic\":\"".$name."\"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"; filename=\"".$file."\"\r\nContent-Type: ".$type."\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(            
                "SessionId: ".$_SESSION['session']."",
                "VersionCode: ".cfg('version_code')."",
                "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            redirect("/meme/me/group"."?msg=".urldecode('Update icon group succes')."&type_msg=success");
    }
```

i want to know how to $file to the image for success upload, cause $_POST only display the filename not with the fullpath.

---

### Update

---

this is the full function in controller i have

```
function one()
    {   
        $filename = $_FILES['icon']['name'];    
        $filedata = $_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'];
        $filetype = $_FILES['icon']['type'];

        two($_POST['group'], $filename, $filedata, $filetype);
    }
```

this function on my helper

```
function two($group, $name, $file, $type)
{   
    $cFile = new CURLFile($file,$type,$name);

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_PORT => "2403",
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://".cfg('api_ip').":2403/sk_group/update_profile_pic",
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n\r\n{\"groupId\":\"".$group."\",\"profile_pic\":\"".$name."\"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"; filename=\"".$cFile."\"\r\nContent-Type: ".$type."\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(            
            "SessionId: ".$_SESSION['session']."",
            "VersionCode: ".cfg('version_code')."",
            "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        redirect("/meme/me/group"."?msg=".urldecode('Update icon group succes')."&type_msg=success");
    }
}
```

> still with same question like i asking..., where the file? and how to post it until success?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php)

Comment: doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46190111/2520628)

From PHP 5.5 and above the CURL will use CURL File to upload the files, for the lower PHP version, you need to manually generate the form boundary and then send the file. The following code sample handles both the cases.

For ease, here's the main part:

```
<?php

$file = "websites.txt";
upload_with_compatibility($file);

function upload_with_compatibility($file){
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.5', '>=')) {
        echo "Upload will be done using CURLFile\n";
        upload($file); //CURL file upload using CURLFile for PHP v5.5 or greater
    }else{
        echo "Upload will be done without CURLFile\n";
        compatibleUpload($file); //CURL file upload without CURLFile for PHP less than v5.5
    }
}

//Upload file using CURLFile
function upload($file){
    $target = "http://localhost:8888/upload_file.php";
    $host = parse_url($target);

    $cFile = new CURLFile($file,'text/plain', $file);
    $data = array(
        'log_file' => $cFile,
    );

    //you can play around with headers, and adjust as per your need
    $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36';
    $curlHeaders = array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36', //change user agent if you want
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'Pragma: no-cache',
        'Referer: http://localhost:8888/upload.php', //you can change referer, if you want or remove it
        'Host: ' . $host['host'] . (isset($host['port']) ? ':' . $host['port'] : null), // building host header
        'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
        'Cookie: __utma=61117235.2020578233.1500534080.1500894744.1502696111.4; __utmz=61117235.1500534080.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)', //adjust your cookie if you want
        'Expect:  '
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER  , true); //we need header
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$agent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // stop verifying certificate
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // enable posting
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // post images 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // if any redirection after upload
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
    $r = curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error = curl_error($curl);
        print_r($error);
    } else {
        // check the HTTP status code of the request
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($resultStatus != 200) {
            print_r($resultStatus);
        }else{
            //successfull
            print_r($r);
        }
    }
    curl_close($curl);
}

//Upload file without using CURLFile, because we are upload a file, so we need to generate form boundry
function compatibleUpload($file){
    $target = "http://localhost:8888/upload_file.php";
    //use this to send any post parameters expect file types
    //if you are not sending any other post params expect file, just assign an empty array
    // $assoc = array(
    //     'name' => 'demo',
    //     'status' => '1'
    // );
    $assoc = array(); //like this

    //this array is used to send files
    $files = array('log_file' => $file);

    static $disallow = array("\0", "\"", "\r", "\n");

    // build normal parameters
    foreach ($assoc as $k => $v) {
        $k = str_replace($disallow, "_", $k);
        $body[] = implode("\r\n", array(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$k}\"",
            "",
            filter_var($v), 
        ));
    }

    // build file parameters
    foreach ($files as $k => $v) {
        switch (true) {
            case false === $v = realpath(filter_var($v)):
            case !is_file($v):
            case !is_readable($v):
                continue; // or return false, throw new InvalidArgumentException
        }
        $data = file_get_contents($v);
        $v = call_user_func("end", explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $v));
        $k = str_replace($disallow, "_", $k);
        $v = str_replace($disallow, "_", $v);
        $body[] = implode("\r\n", array(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$k}\"; filename=\"{$v}\"",
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream",
            "",
            $data, 
        ));
    }

    // generate safe boundary 
    do {
        $boundary = "---------------------" . md5(mt_rand() . microtime());
    } while (preg_grep("/{$boundary}/", $body));

    // add boundary for each parameters
    array_walk($body, function (&$part) use ($boundary) {
        $part = "--{$boundary}\r\n{$part}";
    });

    // add final boundary
    $body[] = "--{$boundary}--";
    $body[] = "";

    // set options
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  , true); //we need header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // stop verifying certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST       => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => implode("\r\n", $body),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Expect: ",
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={$boundary}", // change Content-Type
        ),
    ));
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        print_r($error);
    } else {
        // check the HTTP status code of the request
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($resultStatus != 200) {
            print_r($resultStatus);
        }else{
            //successfully uploaded
            print_r($r);
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```